# How can I scroll then `ion-content` when use the drop-down refresh?

Tags: ionic-framework

When I use the `ion-refresher`, users use the drop-down refresh, the `ion-content` in the process of waiting to get the data can't scroll ,it has to wait for `refresher.complete ()` before they can scroll.

What's the problem caused by?

How can I scroll then  `ion-content` when use the drop-down refresh?

Comment: the ionic version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed the `refresher-content. js`,because the `ion - refresher` will add `overflow:hidden` to `ion-content` style.

According to the demand change this part can solve this problem.